# Magento + Shopfusion singleton is empty

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento with Typo3 (Shopfusion). I've an extension for uploading order images it works in "pure" Magento but in Magento through Shopfusion.

I already debugged Magento as far as I could. In shopfusion the following Singleton leads into an empty array. I checked the getOrderAttachments from "RedPandaPlus_OrderAttachments_Block_Attachments" and found out that it isn't called

Singleton call:

```
$orderAttachments = Mage::getSingleton('redpandaplus_orderattachments/session')->getOrderAttachments();
```

Code of method:

```
class RedPandaPlus_OrderAttachments_Block_Attachments extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
,...
    public function getOrderAttachments($orderId)
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('redpandaplus_orderattachments/orderattachment')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);

        return $collection->toArray();
    }

,...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code, you are missing the $orderId argument in your call:

```
$orderAttachments = Mage::getSingleton('redpandaplus_orderattachments/session')->getOrderAttachments();
```

To help you get the orderId I need to know where you are calling this method.